# hook_field_access does not work

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-hooks

Im trying to use hook_field_access to check if the user has the permission to edit certain fields. The problem is even with a return false, access is not denied.

```
    function applx_field_access($op, $field, $entity_type, $entity, $account){
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: i guess you checked with admin access

Comment: Cannot access the area with an authenticated user role either. I also need to block access to certain administrators without the permission. Granting individual permission is taken care of using user permissions module.

Also changed the hook to return true always and tried with an authenticated user. I get an access denied page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function hook_field_access($op, $field, $entity_type, $entity = NULL, $account = NULL) {
  if ($field['field_name'] == 'field_of_interest' && $op == 'edit') {
    return $account->hasPermission('edit field of interest');
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```